# Node module is not initialized before use

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, module, require

I am trying to create my first node module to publish to NPM and have hit an issue for which I can't find an answer.

I decided to write the module using Promises and keep everything asynchronous. During initialization the module calls a few functions that spend some time accessing the file system.

My problem is the module is not being fully initialized before being called by consuming code that has `required` it.

The full module is on [GitHub](https://github.com/grantcarthew/scalable-blob-store) however here is the initialization code:

```
var uuid = require('node-uuid')
var fsBlobStoreFactory = require('fs-blob-store')
var Promise = require('bluebird')
var validator = require('validator')
var mkdirp = require('mkdirp')
var path = require('path')
var fs = require('fs')

module.exports = BlobStore

function BlobStore(opts) {
  if (!(this instanceof BlobStore)) {
    return new BlobStore(opts)
  }
  this._parseOpts(opts) // <-- Synchronous
  this.currentBlobPath = ''
  this.fsBlobStore = fsBlobStoreFactory(this.opts.blobStoreRoot) // <-- Synchronous
  this._buildBlobPath().then(() => {
    console.log('Blob Store Initialized');
    console.log('Current Blob Path: ' + this.currentBlobPath);
  }) // <-- This takes a while and is asynchronous
}
```

Here is a quick js file I am using for manual tests:

```
var crispyStream = require('crispy-stream');
var opts = {
  blobStoreRoot: '/some/dir/blobs',
  dirDepth: 3,
  dirWidth: 3
}
var sbs = require('./index')(opts)
// Any code under here that uses sbs will fail because the module has not finished loading.

var input = 'pipe this';
var pipable = crispyStream.createReadStream(input);
sbs.write().then((ws) => {
  pipable.pipe(ws);
}
```

As far as I can tell, the module loader within node is synchronous but because the function calls internally are asynchronous, the `require` is returning before the module has finished initializing.

The only solutions I can find are to have the consumers of the module use the 'then' method of the Promise, or use a callback.

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When calling `sbs.write` internally you can call `buildBlobPath` and `then` do the real work. You can cache the result of `buildBlobPath` and not call it every time

Comment: Wow, such an easy solution and I couldn't see it. That would work @VsevolodGoloviznin. Are there any other options? Your idea will work though.

Comment: No other ideas on Sunday morning :)

Comment: Are you actually calling your `Blobstore` function? When you call `require('./index')` it'll return the `exports` object from the module, which isn't a function so attempting to call it with `(opts)` should result in an error.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @piemonkey but the `var sbs = require('./index')(opts)` is calling the function after requiring it. I have the solution thanks to @VsevolodGoloviznin. I would happily give him the answer if I could?

Comment: What I meant was you shouldn't be calling `var sbs = require('./index')(opts)` as you'd get an error telling you that it's not a function. Taking a quick look at your github I can see that you are indeed calling `var sbs = require('./index').create(opts)` as I'd expect, it's just the code in your sample that's incorrect. By the way, I'd be careful with this pattern as it may cause confusing behaviour when node caches the module and you use it in more than one place with different options. I've seen people answer their own question when the answer is in the comments.

Comment: Ah, I see the issue in the question. I fixed it thanks @piemonkey. I copied the `.create()` pattern from another module. The module constructor checks for an instance and calls new if it is not one. This should get around the caching issue you mentioned. I am not an expert yet though.